# Abrir pop-up modal automaticamente ao abrir o site apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma janela Modal que deve ser aberta apenas uma vez ao abrir o site.

Abaixo, tenho o botão que utilizo para abrir a tela Modal, além da div responsável, preciso que este botão seja executado na primeira vez que o site for aberto apenas. Como posso estar fazendo isso?

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/joNF3vycKsA?controls=0" id="iframe_callback" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <!-- Conteúdo do Modal -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo segue código CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 560px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: Sugiro que você modifique a pergunta para facilitar o entendimento, pelo que eu entendi você deseja abrir o modal junto com o site, para isso você deve usar o atributo 'onload' para disparar o evento de abertura. Se você quiser que apareça apenas na primeira visita, você pode utilizar cookies, o correto é usar a session, mais não servirá para está finalidade.

Comment: Não entendo muito de Javascript, poderia me citar algum exemplo? Correto, seria isso mesmo.

Comment: eu iria responder, mais veja primeiro essas opções: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004108/load-popup-onload  | talvez te ajude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função remove ou detached do jQuery para realizar esta função após o clique de fechamento da modal.
O remove irá excluir definitivamente, desligando o elemento do DOM, enquanto o detached vai remover mas vai manter os dados associados ainda no DOM, caso seja necessário algum uso destes. Ficaria bem simples a implementação:

```
$("#close").on("click", function(){
     $("#openModal").remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Saberia informar como posso fazer para abrir o 'pop-up' modal automaticamente ao abrir o site?

Comment: Sim, há vários modos, mas seria legal você utilizar o jQuery, pois ele possibilita criar muita coisa legal no front. Você pode usar o seguinte método:                                                    

```$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openModal').modal('show');
});```